# RavenDB does not store my new documents

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

This is my code of storing a new list of my data to documents:

```
using (var session = DocumentStoreHolder.Store.OpenSession())
{

    //This list is used to put in the database -- Careful!!!
    List<classA> List_01 = new List<classA>();

    //This list is from database, used to compare with the new coming data. 
    //We will check with the list got from data.
    List<ClassA> List_02 = session.Query<classA>().ToList();

    //This uses the method Except to remove the duplicates between the new data 
    //and the current list of matches in database.Return data is the new match 
    //that is not existing in DB 

     List_01 = List_02.Except(List_00, new IdComparer()).ToList();
     foreach (classA data in List_01)
     {
         //Why does it not store data in DB?!?!?!?!?
         session.Store(data);
      }
     session.SaveChanges();
}
```

After I compare two lists together. The problem is that the session seems not store my data after all. I don't know what is wrong in my code. Any idea?

Comment: May I offer some feedback? Type names should be capitalized, but variables should not. "List_01" and "List_02" are vague variable names, use something more descriptive. List<ClassA> itemsToStore = new List<ClassA>()

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're calling .Store(_match). Did you mean to call .Store(data)?

Also, note that your objects will be in the database after you call .SaveChanges. Calling .Store assigns the ID and tells Raven you want to store them, but it won't take affect until .SaveChanges is called.

Comment: Sorry, that was my typo, in my code, that is .Store(data). And I already have SaveChanges, but none of my entities is store in my DB.

Comment: OK. There is weirdness in reassigning List_01. How many items are in the List_01 after you call .Except(...).ToList()?

Comment: List_01 is empty first, then it will have some items. It has items in there after .Except()

Comment: If it really has items in it after the .Except call, and .SaveChanges executes successfully, you have items in your database. Are you sure you're pointing at the correct database (not the system database?) What does your connection string look like?

Comment: The code you're showing so far will store data in the database, unless List_01 is empty. If you're sure that's not the case, can you create a simple repro? I'd be glad to look at it and tell you the problem.

Comment: Any idea please?
This is for my old comment. I tried and checked again, even on other machine, it still does not store my value.

Comment: I was afraid the List_01 is empty, but I tried to call it and see it's not empty, there are values in the list.
I tried another thing, I put the List_01 to a new list, called List_04, and when I output List_04, it still shows its values, but when trying to put List_04 in DB, it still doesnt store anything at all.

Comment: Can you send me a zip file containing your solution? I'd be glad to fix the issue for you.

Comment: Im new to stackoverflow, I  tried to find where to send you a message but cant. May you help me with it?

Comment: My email is judahgabriel at gmail. Feel free to email it to me.